# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when trying to fit a KerasCLassifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying to create a partial dependence plot for a neural network I created with keras. To archieve this I have to create a KerasClassifier or KerasRegressor. After having trouble with getting this working using this import:

`from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier`

I tried to use scikeras but with the following code

```
import numpy as np
import lime
import lime.lime_tabular
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df=pd.read_csv("heart.csv")
df.columns=["age", "sex", "chest_pain_type", "resting_blood_pressure", "cholesterol", "fasting_blood_sugar",
            "resting_ecg", "max_heart_rate", "exercise_induced_angina", "st_depression", "st_slope",
            "number_major_vessels", "thalassemia", "heart_attack"]
X=df.drop("heart_attack", axis=1).to_numpy()
y=df["heart_attack"].to_numpy()

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import keras
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

def split_data(X, y):
        return train_test_split(X, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=10)

#   KerasClassifier for PDP
###############################################################################

def create_model_classifier():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(70, activation="relu", input_shape=(13,)))
    model.add(Dense(70, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(70, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(70, activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))

    opt=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
    model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy", keras.metrics.FalseNegatives(), keras.metrics.FalsePositives()])


    return model

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=split_data(X, y)
model_reg = KerasClassifier(model=create_model_classifier)
    
early_stopping=EarlyStopping(monitor="val_loss", patience=10, verbose=0, mode="auto")
history=model_reg.fit(
    X_train,
    y_train,
    epochs=500,
    batch_size=32,
    shuffle=True,
    validation_data=(X_test, y_test),
    callbacks=[early_stopping]
    )
```

I get this Errorcode:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Leonard\Desktop\X AI - Heart Attacks\main.py", line 95, in <module>
    history=model_reg.fit(

  File "C:\Users\Leonard\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 1416, in fit
    super().fit(X=X, y=y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\Leonard\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 747, in fit
    self._fit(

  File "C:\Users\Leonard\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 866, in _fit
    self._check_model_compatibility(y)

  File "C:\Users\Leonard\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scikeras\wrappers.py", line 536, in _check_model_compatibility
    if self.n_outputs_expected_ != len(self.model_.outputs):

TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

And a few warnings because of the parameters in my fit method which don't seem to be the problem. I also get this error even if I only have X_train and y_train in my fit method.

Comment: I Was running into the same error. Just wondering how you fixed this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue, you need to specify the parameter `input_dim` in the input layer. Therefore if your X has 13 columns, change your first layer from

```
model.add(Dense(70, activation="relu", input_shape=(13,)))
```

to

```
model.add(Dense(70, activation="relu", input_dim=13))
```

and it should work

Answer (score -1):

`scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier` is different from `keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier`. It requires a `tf.keras.Model`, which has a different syntax.

Below is just an example

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def create_model_classifier():
    inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(13,))
    x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(70, activation=tf.nn.relu)(inputs)
    outputs = tf.keras.layers.Dense(70, activation=tf.nn.relu)(x)
    model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model
```

Documentation:
https://scikeras.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/scikeras.wrappers.KerasClassifier.html

Comment: Are you sure this is causing the error becauce in this [link](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/quickstart.html) from the scikeras documentation the model is implemented pretty much the same as mine

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. In the tutorial, it uses `tf.keras.Sequential` which help you infer the input and output automatically. However,  `keras.Sequential` seems like doesn't do that for you. Perhaps, you could just use `tf.keras.Sequential` instead

Comment: I have tried this now. I imported tensorflow and tried using `tf.keras.Sequential` and `tf.keras.models.Sequential` but got the same error so there sadly seems to be another problem.

Comment: FYI @Leonard's link is to the right docs (https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/), the readthedocs.io link is broken

Answer (score -1):

SciKeras supports Sequential models.

The issue seems to be that the batch norm layer messes with the the `tf.keras.Model.outputs` attribute. I think it's supposed to go after your input.

Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np

X = np.ones((100,1))
y = np.zeros((100,))

from keras.layers import Dense, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Sequential
from scikeras.wrappers import KerasClassifier

def create_model_classifier():
    model=Sequential()
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="relu", input_shape=(1,)))
    model.add(Dense(1,activation="sigmoid"))
    model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
    return model

model_reg = KerasClassifier(model=create_model_classifier)
    
model_reg.fit(X, y)
```

Comment out or move your `BatchNormalization` layer after your input layer and it should work (the latter is probably what you want).

Also, you should be using `import tensorflow.keras ...` not `import keras ...`.